# Android Studio - Fragment button action

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button, fragment

I tried to make an application that shows a fragment at start then you can change that fragment to an other one with a button in the first fragment. But when I put the button action in the fragments java, it won't start and I get the nullpointerexception error. Could you tell me why?

```
public class Fragment_main extends Fragment {

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button button_inditas = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button_inditas);
    button_inditas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment_1()).commit();
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I put the button action in the fragments java, it won't start and I get the nullpointerexception error. Could you tell me why?

Well I see some errors on your code...

First of all you can't call `getView()` if you haven't inflated one, it means that you **MUST** inflate a view as i'll put on my answer and then you can avoid the `getView()` and use that `view` itself.

And instead of returning the inflater you have to return your `View`

This is how your `Fragment` should look like:

```
 public class Fragment_main extends Fragment {

    public Fragment_main() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
        Button button_inditas = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_inditas);
        button_inditas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();

         fragmentTransaction.add (R.id.content_frame, new Fragment_1());
         fragmentTransaction.commit ();


        });
    return rootView;

    }
}
```

Comment: it still gives the error on line 22 so the fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment_1()).commit();

Comment: but i think i just figured why. Because content_frame is in the main activity layout not in the fragments layout.

Comment: No, i dont know how. :/ I am really a beginner.

Comment: So you want to move from one Fragment to another one right?

Comment: Yes, thats what i want to do.

Comment: Test my edit please :), just copy and paste all of my code to your project don't forget to add the empty constructor.

Comment: It works. I just had to replace instead of add, but it works flawlessly. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to inflate the view first and use the view returned by that instead of getView ().

```
View view = inflater.inflate (...);
```

and then

```
... = (Button) view.findView(...);
```

This happens because the view that is returned by getView () hasn't been created yet, so getView() returns null.